# How to change access to another container in a pod

Tags: containers, openshift, kubernetes-pod

We have two container in one pod. One container is a nginx-forwarder and the other one is the normal application container. I want to access to the app-container via `oc.exe` to get the `jboss server.log`.
I executed the following command:
`oc exec <pod-name> cat <path-2-serverlog>/server.log <local path>/server.log`
But the default container is the nginx forwarder and therefore the directories included in  are not existing.

Error Message:

> Defaulting container name to nginx-jwt-forwarder. Use 'oc describe
> pod/<pod-name> -n <oc-project>' to see all of the containers in this
> pod. cat: <path-2-serverlog/server.log: No such file or directory cat:
> c:/temp/server.log: No such file or directory command terminated with
> exit code 1

How can I switch to the app-container instead of the default nginx?

Answer (score 1):

In this case `oc exec` inherits its params from `kubectl exec`.
Just run your command as follows.
`oc exec $pod -c $container_name $command`

For example.
`oc exec mypod -c ruby-container date`
https://www.mankier.com/1/oc-exec